# Payu money payment gateway

Tags: react-native

I have installed react-native-payumoney . After installation when I run my project it's showing error saying that :-

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
>     Output:  C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Payu\android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:981: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/layout_anchorGravity' with config ''.
>     C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Payu\android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:981: error: resource previously defined here.

```
    I tried to delete the attr/layout_anchorGravity .But when I run the project again it automatically installed. PLease help me to solve the isssue.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding these two lines in dependencies section of your ***android/app/build.gradle*** file and it should work.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```